# Programmatically created button not firing event in custom view in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

On iOS, I created a button programmatically but the event is not firing.

```
UIButton * anyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[anyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleAnyButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
anyButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, 350, 22, 22);
[self addSubview:anyButton];
```

The code is placed inside a custom view (not custom view controller), but I cannot make it fire the event. The press animation is not showing. The custom view has userInteractionEnabled enabled. I also tried using storyboard to create another button on the same view and that one is working. The button code is done in initWithFrame. Must be some simple error I haven't caught and I have been pounding my head over this one for hours.

EDIT:

The event handler:

```
-(void) handleAnyButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSLog(@"handleAnybutton called");
}
```

EDIT2:
The above button codes is done within a [self setup] of class PKLocationsSelectionView.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And this view was created programmatically within the view controller (PKLocSelectionViewController) responsible for this hierarchy:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    CGFloat fieldsHeight = 88;
    UIView * view = [[PKLocationsSelectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, fieldsHeight)];

    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: How is the handleAnyButton method defined?

Comment: Hi I edited the post to include the event handler.

Comment: This actually works for me. You need to change though the [self addSubview:anyButton]; to [[self view] addSubview:anyButton];

Comment: There is no self.view within this view. I'm adding this code in view itself, not in view controller.

Comment: This code is all correct. Maybe we need to see more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your button frame

```
anyButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, 350, 22, 22);
```

is outside of parent bounds

```
CGFloat fieldsHeight = 88;
UIView * view = [[PKLocationsSelectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, fieldsHeight)];
```

Comment: Yeah, i was getting at that with my questions ;).

Comment: Thank you all. What a stupid mistake and I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: Could it be the Button is not fully enclosed within the coordinates of the container (PKLocationsSelectionView) view?

The height of the PKLocationsSelectionView is 88 from your code and the position of the button seems to be outside this.  I think if the button is not enclosed within the frame of the superview then it won't receive touches.

Comment: I don't think this matter though. With with the one I created in storyboard and I tried using UIButton it could work. I know because I've done it before.

Comment: hmm, haven't used storyboard yet, all my buttons use this syntax but were written prior to ios 6, works for me.

Comment: Yeah, I think when you write UIButton instead of id, you don't have to manually cast it if you want to access properties specific to UIButton. That's the only difference I know of.

Comment: id means that you expect to take any object.

Comment: Yes, the sender (Button) is an object in my case.  best of luck @huggie.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still figuring out whether that was actually blocked by some other view. But that post (by Adam Lockhart?) was already pulled.

Comment: For your new edit, why is that so? For example, UISearchBar is a custom view which has at least a UITextField as well as two buttons, one with the "x" and one with the bookmark. It's a complex hierarchy but user is still able to set use the field as well as the buttons. It was my intention to create something like the UISearchBar (in fact, that was what I used and which I'm replacing)

Comment: I want to put it in this view which contains this complexity, so I can use it as a entity (such as animation, hiding, etc) instead of manipulating each of the views one by one.

Comment: by chance is the containing view a UIImageView?  Also, are any of the views in the hierarchy NOT user interaction enabled.  As to your question, i'm basing it on a post i read but of course can't find it now

Comment: What are the CGRect values for the container view?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works for me:

```
MyCustomView.m: 

#import "MyCustomView.h"

@implementation MyCustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(greet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:@"Greet" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self addSubview:button];

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) greet:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"greet!");
}
```

And here is the ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyCustomView *view = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:view];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and change your View initialization code in `viewDidLoad`, to give a static frame and see if it works..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    CGFloat fieldsHeight = 88;
    //See the change in below line.. instead of using self.view.bounds.size.width
    // I used a static width.. 320 pixel for the moment..
    UIView * view = [[PKLocationsSelectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, fieldsHeight)];

    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` view hierarchy of controller will not be drawn completely..So `self.view.bounds.size.width` may be giving incorrect values.. To access `self.view.frame` and `self.view.bounds`, you should atleast wait until `viewWillAppear` gets called.

Also, your button origin.y is at 350 which in a view which has maximum height of only 88.. Any control outside parent's frame won't receive touches..

Comment: Thanks! The button went out of frame.

Comment: Oh I guess Alexey beat you first so I had to give it to him. Sorry. :p